# Using object inside constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, stl, constructor

I am creating my own vector class inheriting the STL one. I have a problem while creating the object.

Here is my class.

```
using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class ArithmeticVector : public vector<T>{
public:
    vector<T> vector; //maybe I should not initalize this
    ArithmeticVector(){};
    ArithmeticVector(T n) : vector(n){
   //something here
};
```

In main; I am calling this;

```
ArithmeticVector<double> v9(5);
```

or

```
ArithmeticVector<int> v1(3);
```

What I want is creating `v9` vector or `v1` vector just like STL vector type. But what I get is a vector inside my newly created object. I want my object to be a vector at first.

Maybe I should use that `v1` object inside constructor ? Thanks for help.

Comment: IIRC you should not even inherit from stl containers. Better to make a wrapper around vector than to inherit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need elementwise operations and math on a `std::vector`, use `std::valarray`. If not, I don't see why you are subclassing `std::vector`.

Don't inherit form `std::` containers, they don't have a virtual destructor and will blow up in your face if deleted from a pointer to base.

**EDIT** If you need to define operations on `std::vector`, you can by defining the operators outside of the class, and using its public interface.

Comment: what i want is this: i want those v1 and v9 to be a vector like `vector<T> foo; foo(5);`  but with my implementation i get a normal vector inside my useless v1 v9 objects. I need to treat v1 and v9 like a vector, not a vector container.

Comment: @Akeara: what do you want to *do* with this class?

Comment: i want to define new functions to work with my vectors like adding or dividing two vectors. But to do that i need to inherit vector class. But as i stated whenever i call those constructors, i don't get a v1 vector or v9 vector. I need to create those v1 and v9 as vectors.

Comment: @Akeara no, you do not need to inherit from vector. You just think you do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code that you posted cannot compile because of this line:

```
public:
    vector<T> vector; //maybe i should not initalize this
```

you should see this error:

```
 declaration of ‘std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> > ArithmeticVector<T>::vector’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:171: error: changes meaning of ‘vector’ from ‘class std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >’
```

because you are introducing the whole std namespace above the class template declaration which makes the name "vector" visible, and then you use it to declare an object. That's like writing "double double;".

> What i want is creating v9 vector or v1 vector just like STL vector
>   type.

If this is what you want, here is the code that does it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template
<
    class Type
>
class ArithmeticVector
:
    public std::vector<Type, std::allocator<Type> >
{
    public: 

        ArithmeticVector()
        :
            std::vector<Type>()

        {}

        // Your constructor takes Type for an argument here, which is wrong: 
        // any type T that is not convertible to std::vector<Type>::size_type
        // will fail at this point in your code; ArithmeticVector (T n)
        ArithmeticVector(typename std::vector<Type>::size_type t)
            :
                std::vector<Type>(t)
        {}

        template<typename Iterator>
        ArithmeticVector(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
        :
            std::vector<Type>(begin, end)
        {}

};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ArithmeticVector<double> aVec (3);  

    return 0;
}
```

If you are interested in arithmetic operations on vectors which are different than the algorithms defined in STL (accumulate, etc), instead of concentrating on the vector class and adding member functions, you can consider writing generic algorithms for vectors that expect specific vector Concepts in stead. Then you don't have to think about inheritance at all, and your generic algorithms can work on different Concepts of a vector.